# Using wget to download or extract links from a JavaScript element

Tags: javascript, download, extract, wget, text-extraction

I am having difficulty using wget on a website that has a list of downloadable files within a Javascript element. Wget just saves some .js, .css and .ico files.

I know I am using the correct wget commands because it does work when I try to point it to a specific file (e.g., example.com/files/specific_file.txt). But trying to wget example.com/files/ doesn't.

My questions is: how can I use wget to download those files? Would I have to parse the page first? Or is there a way of inserting something like [A-Z] and then [1-9] to the URL so that it finds files like abc.txt or 123.txt, since downloading specific files does work?

Also, a secondary question, if I wanted to just get the links to the files rather than downloading all the files, is adding --spider to wget all that's needed (together with -r and so on)?

Comment: When you open `example.com/files/` in the browser, what do you get?

Comment: Probably the list is loaded dynamically with JavaScript. wget is not a browser, it won't execute JavaScript, so it won't find those links either. You need a headless browser or perhaps you could analyze the page in the browser devtools to find out how the list is assembled (probably from some API call) and then replicate that.